# How to throw `InterruptedException` while junit testing my class?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit, interrupted-exception

I am trying to write some junit for a class which is using CountDownLatch and I am using jmockit library for junit testing.

```
public class MappedData {

    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> mapped1 = new AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>();
    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> mapped2 = new AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>();
    private static final CountDownLatch firstSet = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getMapped1Table() {
    try {
        firstSet.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return mapped1.get();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getMapped2Table() {
    try {
        firstSet.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return mapped2.get();
    }
}
```

What is the easiest way to make sure that in the `getMapped1Table` and `getMapped2Table` method - I am able to throw an `InterruptedException` so that I can cover that scenario as well. If you take a look into those two methods, I have a catch block which I am not able to cover.

```
MappedData.getMapped1Table()
```

Is there any way I can make sure that my above two methods are throwing `InterruptedException`?

**Update:-**

What I am trying to do is - how to get firstSet.await() to throw an InterruptedException when I am junit testing.

Comment: you're throwing an `IllegalStateException` ... you'd test for that.

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to get `firstSet.await()` to throw an `InterruptedException` when you're testing. Is that correct?

Comment: @MikeB: Yes that's what I need.. Sorry I was not clear enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to write the test with JMockit:

```
public class MappedDataTest
{
    @Test
    public void getMappedTableHandlesInterruptedException(
        @Mocked final CountDownLatch anyLatch) throws Exception
    {
        final InterruptedException interrupt = new InterruptedException();
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{ anyLatch.await(); result = interrupt; }};

        try {
            MappedData.getMapped1Table();
            fail();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            assertSame(interrupt, e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to pass `anyLatch` instance value to `getMappedTableHandlesInterruptedException` test method or not?

Comment: No, it's passed indirectly by JMockit through the JUnit test runner; this is automatic and transparent.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096026/how-to-pass-null-string-to-a-private-method-using-jmockit-while-unit-testing-it) on jmockit. See if you can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Call the method in a sperate thread, then interrupt that thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      MappedData.getMappedTable();
    }
});

t.start();

t.interrupt();
```

Comment: great idea! simple and effective! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a mocking library such as [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/). You will need a way to inject the mock dependency. Generally this is done through a constructor, but since your field is `static` you'll probably want to add a setter.

```
public static void setFirstSet(CountDownLatch latch)
{
    firstSet = latch;
}
```

The rest of this example is for Mockito.

In your test, create a mock `CountDownLatch`:

```
CountDownLatch mockLatch = mock(CountDownLatch.class);
```

Then stub the method to throw the exception:

```
when(mockLatch.await()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
```

Next inject the mock:

```
MappedData.setFirstSet(mockLatch);
```

Finally call the method under test:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> result = MappedData.getMapped1Table();
```

I've never used jmockit, but from a quick a quick google search suggests this is the way to do it:

```
final CountDownLatch mockLatch = new CountDownLatch();
new Expectations(mockLatch){
    {
        mockLatch.await();
        result = new InterruptedException();
    }
};
MappedData.setFirstSet(mockLatch);
Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> result = MappedData.getMapped1Table();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using jmockit library currently in my code base. If possible, can you provide an example for that? Sorry I was not clear enough. I will edit question to add that as well.

Comment: I edited what I think is how to do it with jmockit. I was able to find that by googling, I would definitely suggest trying that first in the future. http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.in/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html