# How to pass null string to a private method using jmockit while unit testing it?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

Below is my private method in my `DataTap` class and I am trying to junit test this private method using jmockit -

```
private void parseResponse(String response) throws Exception {
    if (response != null) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

So below is the junit test I wrote but for null case, it is throwing NPE somehow on the junit test itself.

```
DataTap tap = new DataTap();
Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", "hello");

// this line throws NPE
Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", null);
```

So my question is - Is there any way I can pass `null string` to `parseResponse` method using JMOCKIT as part of junit testing?

This is what I am seeing on that line -

> The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Object[] for
>   the invocation of the varargs method invoke(Object, String, Object...)
>   from type Deencapsulation. It could alternatively be cast to Object
>   for a varargs invocation

Comment: That code should work. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This what I can see on that line `The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to Object[] for the invocation of the varargs method invoke(Object, String, Object...) from type Deencapsulation. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a varargs invocation` and it is indeed failing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A quick glance [at the documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Deencapsulation.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) suggests that what you're trying to do with that signature is not possible:

> ...if a null value needs to be passed, the Class object for the parameter type must be passed instead

If that's the case, then pass in the `Class` object as well as the instance.

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Makoto. I tried this and I got `Invalid null value passed as an Argument 1`. Any suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: Pass the Class object *instead* of `null`, not in addition to it: `Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", String.class)`. Because of method overloading, JMockit needs to know the type of each parameter, so that it can find the desired method through Reflection; such a type can only be determined from a non-null argument *or* by explicitly passing it in the call to `invoke(...)`.

Comment: Docs now at:  http://jmockit.org/tutorial/ReflectionUtilities.html#deencapsulatingMethods

Comment: @jordanpg:  Feel encouraged to edit the answer with the new docs.

Comment: Answer seems vague.  I had to invoke method with null list arg.  this worked: Deencapsulation.invoke(theObject, "methodName", List.class);

Answer (score 0):

Do what the error says. That is, change the line to this:

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", (Object) null);
```

Comment: Thanks tbodt. I tried this and I got `Invalid null value passed as an Argument 0`. Any suggestion what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did like that when I need to pass null String in toString method i.e via casting the `null` into required type

```
mockedObject.toString((String) null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the convenience method and you need to use the full method.  There are two methods to invoke a method on an object instance.  The first method works by getting the parameterTypes from the nonNullArgs.

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(instance, methodName, nonNullArgs);
Deencapsulation.invoke(instance, methodName, parameterTypes, methodArgs);
```

You need to pass in the parameterTypes if one of the args is null like this:

```
DataTap tap = new DataTap();
String response = null;
Class[] parameterTypes = { String.class };
Deencapsulation.invoke(tap, "parseResponse", parameterTypes, response);
```